# Array of dates returns object System datetime not the actual value of the array

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Question is I have a function call "GetDatesBetween" what this does is looks at my two datepickers leave_s_dp and leave_e_dp and gets the dates between them. I then want to turn this array into a string for use in my full_range text box, But it always returns System.DateTime[]. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public:
List<DateTime> ^GetDatesBetween(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    List<DateTime> ^allDates = gcnew List<DateTime>();

    for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
    {
            allDates->Add(date.Date);
    }



    return allDates;

}


private: 
System::Void submit_button_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             array<DateTime> ^dates = GetDatesBetween(leave_s_dp->Value.Date, leave_e_dp->Value.Date)->ToArray();

             //array<DateTime> ^dates = GetDatesBetween(leave_s_dp->Value, leave_e_dp->Value)->ToArray();


             String ^ days_between = dates->ToString();




             full_range_text->Text = days_between;


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `ToString()` on an array. That doesn't do what you expect it to. It's not clear exactly what you *do* expect it to do, but it's almost certainly not what you want.

You quite possibly want to call `string.Join`, e.g.

```
dates_between = String::Join(", ", dates);
```

That will just use the default date format though - which may not be what you want either.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, how ever it still gives me System.DateTime[]. @Jon Skeet

Comment: @Snowman288: Really? So the text of `days_between` is `System.DateTime[]`? That seems unlikely... what version of .NET are you using?

Comment: The correct syntax is `System::String::Join` (you use the `::` operator as in plain C++ for static member access).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Fixed, thanks. Is the `System::` part necessary in this case, given that the OP is already using `String` in an unqualified way?

Comment: You're right, you can drop `System::`. I just read OP's code too quickly and spotted the `System::Object` then assumed he didn't have a `using namespace System;` clause in the code, but the unqualified names tell otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your input as well @Lucas Trzesniewski

Comment: @Snowman288: So what did you do differently between your comment at 16:11 UTC and now?